# how many blocks are in the single disk page? Buffer size equal to sector size?

Tags: hard-disk

There are some confusions regarding the sizes of disks.

I'm trying to calculate the size of a single page of a disk.
I want to know how many blocks exist in the typical disk's single page? 
And, if I see the specifications of hard disks, it says "buffer size = 512 bytes" is that equivalent to the sector size?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "single page of a disk". Virtual memory has pages, disks don't.

Harddisks have a physical sector size (today usually 4096 bytes) and a logical sector size (usually 512 bytes). That's because long ago, harddisks used to have a physical sector size of 512 bytes, and the logical/physical sizes were introduced to keep it (somewhat) compatible.

You can find out the physical and logical sector size of your harddisk for example with `fdisk -l`.

In a specification of a hard disk, the "buffer size" usually means the amount of internal RAM of the harddisk controller used for buffering. But that's a lot more than 512 bytes. I have no idea what particular specification with "buffer size = 512 bytes" you read, so I cannot comment on that.